# Component not rendering when using vue-template

Tags: templates, vuejs2, components

I have the following...

main.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <header></header>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {}
</script>
```

header.vue

```
<template>
    <div>{{ message }}</div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data: () => {
            return {
                message: 'Dashboard'
            }
        }
   };
</script>
```

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Header from './header.vue'
import App from './main.vue'
Vue.component("header", Header);
new Vue(App).$mount('#km-viewport')
```

But when I run this the header component is never rendered. What am I missing? Does using the vue-template webpack plugin require something special here?

I have looked at a couple similar stack overflows and I have tried to use `components: { Header }` instead but that still doesn't work.

I also tried...

main.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <header></header>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import Header from './header.vue'
    export default {
      components:{
        "header": Header
      }
    }
</script>
```

header.vue

```
<template>
    <div>{{ message }}</div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data: () => {
            return {
                message: 'Dashboard'
            }
        }
   };
</script>
```

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './main.vue'
Vue.component("header", Header);
new Vue(App).$mount('#km-viewport')
```

Comment: Where's the `import Header from './header.vue'`, you have one, don't you?

Comment: Sorry it is in the main.js I deleted it on accident when copying but that doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Yours is a frequent problem:

> ## [Vue warn]: Do not use built-in or reserved HTML elements as component id: `name`

In your case `<header>` is a reserved HTML element.

The same happens to `<main>`, `<article>` and so on.

**Solution:** Rename your `header` component to other name.

Example (I renamed `header` to `header2`):

**main.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <header2></header2>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import Header from './header.vue'
    export default {
      components:{
        "header2": Header
      }
    }
</script>
```

**header.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>{{ message }}</div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                message: 'Dashboard'
            }
        }
   };
</script>
```

**Bonus:** [Don't use arrow functions](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Data-and-Methods) as in `data: () => {`, that will give you problems. Use like `data() {`. This rule applies to `methods`, `computed`s, `watchers` and all other Vue instance options.

Comment: I tried this by adding a prefix like you suggest but it still isn't working.

Comment: What prefix? Did I suggest a prefix?

Comment: kinda instead of adding a postfix (your suggestion with the 2) I created a prefix (my-header). This is since according to the HTML spec they are supposed to be prefixed